# Cover polygon with rectangles

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I need to cover some polygon with rectangles here's an example :[image]

The black figure in a black square is the polygon that i need to cover with those green rectangles but i need to do it more efficiently that just make a net like i did. Because as you can see there can be place more green rectangles if i moved them. I don't know where to search for such info. What should i look up to get what i need ?

Rectangles inside are fixed size(just not as big as polygon it self), one for all like in the picture, they can be places vertically and horizontally, i want to fill the polygon as much as it can fit it inside of it, this polygon is just for example, there can be different polygons with holes in them for example that black small square is a hole.

Comment: Your question is not precise at all: how many rectangles do you want? What is their size? Are they equal rectangles? Do the sides of the covered polygon have only vertical or horizontal directions?

Comment: If you quantize the available area into small squares you could approximate it with a 0-1 [ILP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) maximization problem.  There are linear programming solvers out there.